# Youtube comments censoring

Tags: youtube

How does Youtube comments censoring work? Is it a fixed word list, regular expressions, or a learning AI? I sometimes get my comments deleted without clear reason

Answer (score 4):

It's all that you've mentioned + channel authors can set their own words list to be censored. See i. e. [at Channel level comment settings.](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/9483359?hl=en)

Comment: Is it possible to see somewhere a list of words and phrases they think are inappropriate?

Comment: I mean Youtube itself, not channel authors

Comment: None that I'm aware of.

Answer (score 1):

I have also faced this issue several times and have contacted google support for this issue seems like you are never told who removed your comments so unless you get a strike for breaking the rules you never know who removed them.