# YouTube censoring (comments)

Tags: youtube, comments, delete

There is already a question about [How does YouTube censoring work](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/145574/youtube-comments-censoring).

My question:

- is there any place to retrieve the deleted comments?
- or, is there any possible appeal, support contact?

Some of my comments get deleted on YouTube within seconds (it's not the channel owner), but the comments are really within the rules as defined by Google. Pretty annoying :(